# Why does the civicrm upgrade stop after each step of the upgrade eg at 4.7.19 then again at 4.7.20

Tags: upgrade

Not used to seeing this but one site just stopped at each step of the journey.

Comment: I have seen this happen when the previous drupal/ module folder can still be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the code, retry and skip seems to be shown with the value set for debug. Note `Enable Debugging` if it is turned on/off on `Administer-> System Settings -> Debugging and Error Handling`.

Need to confirm this on another upgrade I do, but for now, it seems retry and skip [would show up if debugging is enabled](https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php#L163) and the upgrade would progress only after [Retry button is clicked](https://github.com/jitendrapurohit/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates//CRM/Queue/Page/Runner.tpl#L128). So for continuous upgrade, one should have `debug` set to `No`?

Comment: is it worth thinking about having a msg pop up at /upgrade to say 'you have debug enabled'?

Comment: It happens to me too. I can see how I get an error to the console with PHP notice and warnings printed on a json response. What's strange is that I initially have all debug modes turned off.

Comment: **Notice**: Undefined index: CRM_Upgrade in (...)/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Service.php on line 131

 **Warning**: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in (...)/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php on line 722

**Warning**: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in (...)/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php on line 724
{"is_error":0,"exception":null,"last_task_title":"Upgrade DB to 4.7.19","numberOfItems":"17","is_continue":1}

Comment: Disabling display_errors at server side finally solved it for me.